# Trigger GitHub action on merge of Pull Request with specific tag

Tags: github, pull-request, github-actions

I am trying to use GitHub actions to automatically create a release when a Pull Request with the tag `Update` is merged.

At the moment, my workflow triggers when a Pull Request is merged, but I am not sure how to make the workflow only continue if the Pull Request has the `Update` tag.

**Current Workflow**

```yaml
name: Create Release

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]

jobs:
  release:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true

    ...rest of workflow...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'Update')
```

From this https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-an-array